# Assorted colors for stacked pyplot barchart

Tags: python, colors, matplotlib, scipy

I need to display the stacks of a stacked bar chart in different colors. The number of stacks is not entirely predictable, it could be anything between 3 and 30. Is there a "classy" way of creating a color dictionary of highly contrasting colors that could be iterated and passed to the "color" attribute of pyplot.bar? Obviously I could hard-code a bunch of predefined colors, but I assume that there is a more elegant way to do that?

Comment: None of the colormaps supplied would do?